# Some objects not materializing (but are in query response) - inheritance issue?

Tags: breeze

I've just added a fourth layer of expand to my query - ie:

```
       .expand("..., ScanDates.Printouts.BMDSites, ...");
```

And I've discovered that although the data is being returned in the response, it is not populating the objects below "Printouts" (ie. patient.ScanDates.Printouts.BMDSites is an empty array, despite several elements being returned in the response).

I've altered the MaxExpansionDepth on the controller action, and there are no errors appearing on the console or server side. I've also successfully filled BMDSite objects by just querying for them individually, but that would mean ten or twenty return trips to the server... not ideal.

***Edit:** I've just tried several other queries, and it seems that even if I'm just doing a single expand (ie: .expand("BMDSites")), the same problem occurs - data is in response, but not materialized into entities. When I query just for the BMDSites, (say for a specific Printout) the array is filled and materialized properly.*

***Edit 2:** It just occurred to me that the Printout class is the base class of a TPH inheritance hierarchy... Looking around a bit, I suspect that this is likely the source of the issue.*

Thanks so much for any ideas!
-Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it had nothing to do with inheritance after all... In creating a simplified model for Jay, I of course found that it worked just fine. Adding back in the features that I thought were irrelevant, I eventually broke it, and replicated my issue by adding in some [NotMapped] properties that were providing some easy access to the list of BMDSites. For example, in a class derived from Printout:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public BMDSite _Ud = null;

    [NotMapped]
    public BMDSite Ud
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Ud == null)
            {
                _Ud = BMDSites.Find(b => b.Region == Region.Forearm_UD);
            }
            return _Ud;
        }
    }
```

Upon adding this back in, once again, my list of BMDSites were not populating *(**edit**- more specifically, any BMDSite that was touched by an unmapped property was being excluded from the list of BMDSites)*. Turns out that the JSON.net classes that Breeze uses don't look at [NotMapped] (which makes sense, as it is serialization, not DB mapping)... By adding a reference to JSON.net in my EF model, and adding it's equivilent tag - ie: [NotMapped, JsonIgnore], it doesn't look at the properties, and everything works just fine.

**Bottom line (for those that skim)... code above causes issues, code below works fine:**

```
    [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
    public BMDSite _Ud = null;

    [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
    public BMDSite Ud
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Ud == null)
            {
                _Ud = BMDSites.Find(b => b.Region == Region.Forearm_UD);
            }
            return _Ud;
        }
    }
```

Cheers,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

I would start by insuring that the 'expand' you are doing is in fact valid by trying the exact same query on the server using 'Include's.  If this fails then the issue is likely with your model.  Breeze 'expand's get turned into EF 'Include's.

If the query works in pure EF, then can you detail the relevant properties in your model and what the inheritance hierarchy looks like so that we can try to replicate your issue?

Comment: Thanks so much for the response Jay. Doing the expands as Includes on the server worked fine, so I started to create a simplified model to post/replicate the issue - which of course worked fine. I continued to add features (that I thought were irrelevant) until I broke it again. Turned out to be some [NotMapped] properties on the Printout object. Solution was to add a reference to JSON.net in the EF model, and to add [JsonIgnore] in addition to [NotMapped]. I'll post a bit more detail below, in case anybody else runs into the same. Thanks again for your time + hard work - love Breeze. -Brad

Comment: Any additional detail would be great, and please mark this question as answered so that others know that this is solvable. thx.